# What exactly is the client secret for Google OAuth2?

Tags: android, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin, google-developers-console

In [Google's OIDC guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#server-flow), section `Exchange code for access token and ID token` states that I must provide a `client_secret`.

If I select the relevant client ID from the API console, I do indeed get a JSON file named `client_secret_...`.  However, none of the fields of the JSON object are named secret or anything similar. (The fields are named `client_id`, `project_id`, `auth_uri`, `token_uri`, `auth_provider_x509_cert_url`, and `redirect_uris`.)

So, where do I get this `client_secret`?

Comment: Client secret isn't need for all of the types of credentials you can create which type did you create?  Service account maybe?

Comment: I created a "OAuth Client ID for Android".

Comment: there is your problem them Android doesn't need secret so you wont get one.  you should probably try following this instead https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

Comment: Okay, that explains it. Feel free to write that in an annwer, so I can upvote it and check it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the secrete used to be in the file but alternatively you can also find it by looking at the page were you downloaded your json file and you can also click the button to reset said secret.

[image]

I would make sure that the credentials are looking at are under `OAuth 2.0 client IDs` and not `Service account keys` or `API keys` only the first one needs a secret I believe.

**Update from comments:**  Creating Oauth Client Id for android will not give you a secret because its not needed in android application should should probably be following [Add google sign-in to your android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  If it were that obvious I wouldn't be asking... ;-) Seriously, That page lists only the "Client ID" and the "Creation Date". No "Client secret"...

Comment: Take a screen shot of it please.   I think you have created the wrong type of credentials.

Comment: @DaImTo, that is good answer, but add this link, please
`https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/`
and say, that we need to click on our OAuth string, to get that window